# Flex remove header horizontal separator from Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, separator

Is it possible to remove the horizontal separator which divides the headers with the data?  I managed to remove the vertical ones with mx.skins.Programmatic skin, but could not find a way to remove the horizontal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it... set headerBackgroundSkin="mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin"